# texture is not a template

Tags: c++, cuda

I am using CUDA in Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 for this code:

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <device_launch_parameters.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstddef>

texture<float, 2, cudaReadModeElementType> texRef;
```

It gives me `texture is not a template` error, and there seems to be absolutely nothing I can done in that. All the other CUDA-related code I have tried seemed to compile ok. The file is indeed a `.cu` file, not a `.cpp` file. The CUDA Samples with textures compile correctly for me.

What can possibly be the issue here?

(While there are the same questions, they all suggest that changing a `.cpp` file to a `.cu` file should help, which does not seem to be my case.)

Comment: The code is legal. It is most likely your project setup in VS is broken somehow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your project is trying to compile your file with Cl, not nvcc.

Replace in your .vcxproj project file

```
<ClCompile Include="myfile.cu" />`
```

by

```
<CudaCompile Include="myfile.cu" />
```

If you updated cuda, you also need to update your `ExtensionSettings` in project files:

```
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionSettings">
    <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 11.3.props" />
  </ImportGroup>
```

I add that texture references are [deprecated in cuda 11.3](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#texture-reference-api) and instead you should use [texture objects](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#texture-object-api).

Comment: So, it seems it was because of the deprecation. I have just updated to cuda 11.3 today and did not know about it. The .vcxproj file had `CudaCompile`.

Comment: @Valeria It's not the deprecation. I can compile with cuda 11.3 and texture reference.

Comment: then it seems that I have some problems with the setting up CUDA indeed. It worked fine till I updated the drivers. While I can run all the CUDA Samples, for some reason I cannot run the default Visual Studio kernel.cu template if I create it as a new project.

Comment: I get `GPUassert: the provided PTX was compiled with an unsupported toolchain.` error on trying to run anything (though not if I run CUDA Samples). Even if I run the template project.  However, the driver (470.14) & CUDA version (11.3) seem to be compatible from the tables I have found on NVIDIA website.

Comment: @Valeria Did you update also the ExtensionSettings in your project ? (see updated answer) One do not actually update cuda, it is installed aside the previous versions, and eventually one remove the previous version. The toolchain  (BuildCustomizations\CUDA) must be updated in that case.

Comment: Yes, I have the correct CUDA version there. Both CUDA Samples (that work) and all the other code, even the Visual Studio's template for CUDA (does not work) seem to have the same version in the ExtensionSettings.